# Sending an Email through a VBA macro (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've spent the last couple days trying to figure this out, I've managed to stop all the errors, however the email doesn't show up in my inbox. I've tried to change everything up and still it doesn't show up.
The main purpose is to send an entire workbook to an email with a button (I've binded the button to the macro)
Anyways, here's the code I have already

```
Sub Send_mail()
Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "example@email.com"
        .From = "example@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Assunto"
        .Body = "Corpo"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

(ps I did change the email to post this, it's not what I have in the code)

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` which is suppressing your errors and rerun. I anticipate you will get an error then that should help debug this.

Comment: Almost gaurantee that once you remove `On Error Resume Next` you are going to find the error on this line: `.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName`. You are asking vba to attachment the same workbook its running code in, which is probably causing it to trip up. You may need to save a copy of the workbook and attach that file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `.From = "example@email.com"`
Mail will go with attachment from outlook default mail address.
In Microsoft Documentation `From` is not listed while `To, cc, BCC` etc are included . So syntax wise it is wrong. It works for me after removing `.From`

> You can see from list below

```
Methods
Properties
Actions
AlternateRecipientAllowed
Application
Attachments
AutoForwarded
AutoResolvedWinner
BCC
BillingInformation
Body
BodyFormat
Categories
CC
Class
Companies
Conflicts
ConversationID
ConversationIndex
ConversationTopic
CreationTime
DeferredDeliveryTime
DeleteAfterSubmit
DownloadState
EntryID
ExpiryTime
FlagRequest
FormDescription
GetInspector
HTMLBody
Importance
InternetCodepage
IsConflict
IsMarkedAsTask
ItemProperties
LastModificationTime
MarkForDownload
MessageClass
Mileage
NoAging
OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested
OutlookInternalVersion
OutlookVersion
Parent
Permission
PermissionService
PermissionTemplateGuid
PropertyAccessor
ReadReceiptRequested
ReceivedByEntryID
ReceivedByName
ReceivedOnBehalfOfEntryID
ReceivedOnBehalfOfName
ReceivedTime
RecipientReassignmentProhibited
Recipients
ReminderOverrideDefault
ReminderPlaySound
ReminderSet
ReminderSoundFile
ReminderTime
RemoteStatus
ReplyRecipientNames
ReplyRecipients
RetentionExpirationDate
RetentionPolicyName
RTFBody
Saved
SaveSentMessageFolder
Sender
SenderEmailAddress
SenderEmailType
SenderName
SendUsingAccount
Sensitivity
Sent
SentOn
SentOnBehalfOfName
Session
Size
Subject
Submitted
TaskCompletedDate
TaskDueDate
TaskStartDate
TaskSubject
To
ToDoTaskOrdinal
UnRead
UserProperties
VotingOptions
VotingResponse
```